# Are cfc's safe in the application scope

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I'm kind of new with cfml and I am trying to figure out if putting components in the application scope is okay, if everything in the component is `var`'d.

I know that scope is shared by all users but if all the variables are `var`'d in the functions would that prevent people from seeing each others data and/or race conditions?

Thanks

Comment: Depends on what the components do. If the components are truly *stateless* it is safe to store them in a shared scope. Stateless components/functions a) do not store any information from previous requests and b) given specific arguments, always return the same result. As long as all variables in the stateless cfc are local scoped, there is no possibility of race conditions. It is NOT safe to store *stateful* components in a shared scope. That can cause a variety of unexpected and weird results [due to race conditions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcoldfusion%5D%20race%20conditions).

Comment: Can you give us some idea as to what the functions are? What is the goal that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I was mainly just wondering if storing say user function with user info would be safe. I suppose I was trying to get a grasp on what was safe and what wasn't.

Comment: Storing the function in the application scope would be ok.  The user info would be better off in the session scope.

Comment: I think it still depends on what you mean by "user info". It is easy to accidentally create race conditions if you are not cognizant of all the factors in play. BTW, for next time I think you will get a more definitive answer (and avoid having the question closed) if you post a concrete example. It does not have to be fancy, just a small repro-case that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you store in the component belongs to the whole application, like e.g. some page layout data, it is fine to store it in the application scope.

Also, if the component is *stateless*, i.e. all the variables in it are in the local scope, it is safe to store objects created from it in that scope.

Though if the component is *stateful*, i.e. it stores data from previous requests or user specific data in it, it is **not** safe to store objects created from it in the application scope, because this may cause data leakage and other unexpected and unwanted results due to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) or incorrect access.
In that case you should rather store your component in the session scope.

Comment: @brian - A few distinctions that may not be obvious:  1) *RE: belongs to the whole application*  Also relevant is whether the data is read-only or read-write. Application level data like a "total number of users online" could be stored in the app scope, but would still need to be locked to avoid race conditions.  2) *RE: all the variables in it are in the local scope* That literally means all variables. If you forget to `var` scope a single read-write variable, it ends up in the `variables` scope of the CFC, which is essentially the application scope in this specific scenario.

Comment: ... so the answer is "it depends".  As mentioned, it would be helpful to provide more details about what your functions do, so we can provide more specific advice.

Comment: @Leigh I think the read read/write distinction is what I was after thanks for your help in getting my head around it.

Comment: I find a good way to look at it is to imagine creating the variables directly in the application scope. Like say `application.myShoppingCart`. In cases like that it is immediately obvious the code both stores and writes data from previous requests and so would not be safe to store in the application scope.